# neo4j 2.1.2 dbvisualizer connection

Tags: database, neo4j, dbvisualizer

Im trying to connect neo 2.1.2 with DBvisualizer 9.1.5 and I'm getting the following error:  Database connection could not be established for:
   neotest1

An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Long Message:
Unsupported Neo4j version:org.neo4j.jdbc.Version@49cf3b3b

System Information:
Product: DbVisualizer Free 9.1.5
Build: #2105 (2013/12/16 09:38)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Java Version: 1.7.0_45
Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation
OS Name: Windows 8
OS Arch: amd64
OS Version: 6.2

If anyone is familiar with any solution, please advice!
Thank you all.

Comment: which version of neo4j jdbc are you using?

Comment: You re right, Ive found the right one!!  https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/blob/master/README.asciidoc, thank you!!

Comment: The new issue now is the UTF-8 greek chars... :(

Comment: what is the issue? Maybe raise another question.

Comment: Sorry Peter, I dont hane the reputation to post images... I just dont get recognisable characters after query extraction, for the greek characters on values that I have...

Comment: Raise a new question you can also link to external images.